How to debug registerCustomQueryHandler
The following code for a custom Vue Component selector is mentioned in the https://pptr.dev/guides/page-interactions#custom-selectors documentation. When I run this code, I cannot query the HelloWorld component, and I don't know how to debug.
{
  "name": "pptr",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.mjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^22.12.1"
  }
}

import puppeteer, { Puppeteer } from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
    Puppeteer.registerCustomQueryHandler('vue', {
        queryOne: (element, name) => {
            const walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
            do {
                const currentNode = walker.currentNode;
                if (
                    currentNode.__vnode?.ctx?.type?.name.toLowerCase() ===
                    name.toLocaleLowerCase()
                ) {
                    return currentNode;
                }
            } while (walker.nextNode());

            return null;
        },
    });
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://localhost:5173/')
    const textContent = await page.locator('::p-vue(HelloWorld)').map(el => el.textContent).wait()
    console.log(textContent)
    await browser.close()
})()

Exception message：
TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms

I run npm create vite to create the vue project, which contains a HelloWorld component，run npm run dev will start the development server and listen on port 5173.
// package.json file for a Vue project created with Vite.
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
  }
}

Target：

How to debug the registerCustomQueryHandler() function.
Use ::-p-vue(HelloWorld) to find the HelloWorld component.


What do you mean by "debug" this function? What problem are you having with it and what's the purpose of this code in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

The documentation at https://pptr.dev/guides/page-interactions#custom-selectors mentions custom selectors, which are very useful for creating custom selectors based on framework objects or applications. I tried running a custom selector demo, but it was not successful. I was also unable to perform breakpoint debugging on the code within the custom selector.
My goal is to write a custom selector that works for Vue.js and React.js components.

OK, thanks. I suggest [edit]ing that into the question. It sounds like there are two issues here: basic correctness, then entering the function with a breakpoint in the debugger? Can you choose one so the question is tightly scoped? I assume correctness first. The correct syntax for p-selectors is ::-p-vue(HelloWorld), not : -p-vue(HelloWorld). Is this supposed to find the component with the name? What's the current problematic behavior exactly?

I think the code you posted is straight out of the docs, which shows the sample usage. It's always good to reference that.

Sorry, I rely on translation tools for communication. As you can see, there are errors in my question, I have updated my question. My goal is simple: to determine why the example code is not working through debugging and to try to fix it, but I currently don't know how to debug it.

I understand, thanks for your patience. To get help with the example code not working, you'll need to show your full test suite and the page you're testing. Without that, there's not much to say--it's straight out of the docs. What about it doesn't work, exactly?

I will add more details to the problem description again.

Cool, getting closer. Do you have a sample HelloWorld component? Also, what is your package.json? I'd try adding a log in queryOne to make sure it's being invoked (I assume it isn't).

I have already described this: running npm create vite to create a Vue framework project will give you a Vue.js project that includes a HelloWorld component. Then, running npm run dev will start the development server and, by default, listen on port 5173.

Thanks, I see the vite bit now, sorry I missed that. Can you [edit] the package.json into the post? Comments are temporary and the question should stand on its own. While you're at it, I'd include the Vue version you're using too since it'll change over time.
